# How to change journal attribute in Hitachi F900

Tags: storage, replication

To configure **Hitachi Universal Replication**, I need to change the journal attribute from **initial** to **restore**.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have created the initial UR Pair with **DELTA copy**. By changing it to **Entire Copy** journal attributes are changed to master and restore in both sites automatically.